# Type mismatch; result.type (with underlying type T) with -Xstrict-inference compiler option

Tags: scala

I'm trying to enrich the `scala.util.Try` type with a fold method. I have the following implicit to do that:

```
implicit class FoldableTry[T](tryable: Try[T]) {
  def fold[X](failure: Throwable => X)(success: T => X): X = {
    tryable match {
      case Success(result) => success(result)
      case Failure(ex) => failure(ex)
    }
  }
}
```

When I run **sbt compile** with the **-Xstrict-inference** compiler option, I get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : result.type (with underlying type T)
[error]  required: T
[error]         case Success(result) => success(result)
[error]                                         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

How can I fix this error? If I remove the compiler flag it compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running into a [bug (SI-6680)](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6680). I recommend against using -Xstrict-inference as it sounds experimental—notice Paul Phillip's comment:

> -Xstrict-inference was intended only as a coarse hacky start, but it kind of coincided with my departure. I expect it is overflowing with implementation issues.

Comment: Looks like you're right Steve. There are a few other related bugs:

    1. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6680
    2. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7990
    3. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7991

The recommendation is against using the flag as it is still under development.